# Python Множественная линейная регрессия

Tags: python, python-2.x, pandas

```
def compute(self):
  import statsmodels.api as sm
  import pandas as pd
  from bm_stat_methods import trend_modelcoef as tmc,    trend_estimate_model as tem,     trend_estimate_residuals as ter,     trend_estimate_forecast as tef
  from rbs_form.form_data import save_form_data

  with data_utils.get_report_line_table_by_id(5052) as tbl:
    colnames = tbl.colnames
    sample = [tuple(i[k] for k in colnames) for i in tbl.iterrows()]
  df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(sample, columns = colnames)
  ln = len(df.columns)
  if ln <= 0:
    msg = 'No data received'
    log.exception(msg)
    raise Exception(msg)
  endog_var = df.columns[0]
  df[endog_var]= pd.to_numeric(df[endog_var]) 

  add_const = True
  dlen = lambda x: int(round(0.9*len(x)))-1
  exog_var_1=df.columns[1]
  exog_var_2=df.columns[2]
  df[exog_var_1]= pd.to_numeric(df[exog_var_1]) 
  df[exog_var_2]= pd.to_numeric(df[exog_var_2]) 
  df['const'] = pd.Series((1 for i in range(1, len(df)+1)), index=df.index)
  t = df[['const', exog_var_1, exog_var_2]][0:dlen(df)]
  t_test = df[['const', exog_var_1, exog_var_2]][dlen(df):]
  y = df[endog_var][0:dlen(df)]
  y_test = df[endog_var][dlen(df):]

  model = sm.OLS(y, t)
  res = model.fit()
  print res.summary()
  result = []

  variable = ['const', exog_var_1, exog_var_2]
  """for i in range(2):
    result.append({'variable': variable[i], 'params': res.params[i], 'bse': res.bse[i], 'tvalues':res.tvalues[i],
                 'pvalues':res.pvalues[i], 'conf_int_low':res.conf_int()[i][0], 'conf_int_up': res.conf_int()[i][1]})
  """
  print 'var', variable, 'coeff', res.params, 'bse', res.bse, 'tvalues', res.tvalues, 'pvalues', res.pvalues, 'down',  res.conf_int()[0], 'up', res.conf_int()[1]
  return result
```

В общем требуется вывести всю статистику по модели в result, ошибка появляется в коде, который выделен кавычками. KeyError 0.

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rabus/bm/config/lib/rbs_series/codegenerator.py", line 59, in recalculate
    exec code.encode("utf-8") in l_compute_config
  File "<string>", line 81, in <module>
  File "/home/rabus/bm/config/lib/rbs_series/seriestablecombiner.py", line 44, in __init__
    self.key = self.create_key()
  File "/home/rabus/bm/config/lib/rbs_series/seriestablecombiner.py", line 98, in create_key
    skey = serie.get_key()
  File "/home/rabus/bm/config/lib/rbs_series/seriestable.py", line 452, in get_key
    first_elem = self.peek_data()
  File "/home/rabus/bm/config/lib/rbs_series/seriestable.py", line 152, in peek_data
    r = self._get_data()
  File "/home/rabus/bm/config/lib/rbs_series/seriestable.py", line 188, in _get_data
    self.result = self._handle_result(result)
  File "/home/rabus/bm/config/lib/rbs_series/seriestable.py", line 205, in _handle_result
    self._compute_max_lengths(result)
  File "/home/rabus/bm/config/lib/rbs_series/seriestable.py", line 244, in _compute_max_lengths
    if isinstance(row[n], (str, unicode)):
KeyError: 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rabus/bm/config/lib/rbs_series/computeserie.py", line 62, in compute
    result = recalculate(config, False, extra_config)
  File "/home/rabus/bm/config/lib/rbs_series/codegenerator.py", line 62, in recalculate
    raise e
KeyError: 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rabus/bm/config/lib/rbs_series/subprocexec.py", line 107, in calculate
    result = _compute(config, extra_config, connection_string, GetConnection)
  File "/home/rabus/bm/config/lib/rbs_series/computeserie.py", line 79, in compute
    raise e
KeyError: 0
```

Comment: приведите полный "error traceback", чтобы мы не гадали какой текст выделен и какими кавычками...

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/rabus/bm/config/lib/rbs_series/subprocexec.py", line 107, in calculate result = _compute(config, extra_config, connection_string, GetConnection) File "/home/rabus/bm/config/lib/rbs_series/computeserie.py", line 79, in compute raise e KeyError: 0

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для того, чтобы постить код. Под вопросом есть кнопка ["править"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/832777/edit), позволяющая внести правки в вопрос - воспользуйтесь ей. Пока все еще не понятно о какой переменной идет речь ("KeyError: 2" / "KeyError: 0")

Comment: Показывало KeyError: 2, сейчас KeyError: 0. В общем, проблема конкретно в строке, что в кавычках.

Comment: Ошибка `"KeyError"` говорит о том что вы пытаетесь использовать несуществующий ключ в словаре или несуществующий индекс в Pandas Series/DataFrame. Из вашего кода и __неполного__ "error traceback" не видно о какой переменной идет речь. Если вы заинтересованы в получении ответа - то приведите в вопросе ["минимальный, самодостаточный и __воспроизводимый__ пример?"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Сократил код, прикрепил полный traceback

Comment: Похоже в dictionary/Series с именем `row` в функции "_compute_max_lengths()" нет ключа/индекса со значением `0` - опять гадаем, т.к. в приведенном коде данная строка отсутствует...

Comment: Проверил код  в Python 3.6 , естественно взяв предварительно выводы print в скобки. Ошибки не обнаружено. Возможно вы используете не те версии подключаемых библиотек?